# Global dictionary filed for mongoengine documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I want to dynamically update a global dictionary attribute for a collection in mongoengine. My task is to read a number of documents and annotate them with different descriptions. I want to update a global dictionary whenever a new description is added so that it is available for subsequent documents. How is this possible?

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MongoDB is schema-less, you could store the global object in a the collection and it update it that way

```
class NormalDoc(mongoengine.Document)
    attr1 = mongoengine.StringField()

    # global attribute hidden in the collection
    global_dict = mongoengine.DictField()
    is_global = mongoengine.BooleanField(default=False)
```

There are better ways todo this (like putting it in a separate collection), but that would work if I understand correctly